# Hashing password into an object and receiving Promise { <pending> }

Tags: javascript, bcrypt

I am learning to hash string passwords and store them in an object list.

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')

var users = []

async function hashPass(pass)
{
    try {
        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10)
        
        console.log(`Hashing Password: ${pass}`)

        const hashedPass = await bcrypt.hash(pass, salt)

        console.log(`Hashed Password: ${hashedPass}`)

        return hashedPass

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}

const password = hashPass('pass')

users.push({
    'ID': 0,
    'Name': 'Ali',
    'Email': 'alihaisul.me@gmail.com',
    'Password': password
})

console.log(users)
```

OUTPUT:

```
[
  {
    ID: 0,
    Name: 'Ali',
    Email: 'alihaisul.me@gmail.com',
    Password: Promise { <pending> }
  }
]
Hashing Password: pass
Hashed Password: $2b$10$r52Lu1K.WxOEcAdyeMBV4eR3EPGRXsgJjktJMXFGY5F7a.Q6yoH1C
```

I keep getting the "Promise { pending }" in the output. I've researched and tried using async, await, and even the 'then()'. What am I missing here?

Comment: An `async function` always return a `Promise`. `await` it to retrieve the actual return value (i.e. `hashedPass`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `hashPass` function uses the *async/await* keywords it returns a **Promise** object and you are getting that as the output.

You need to *await* the result of the `hashPass` function before pushing the new user object into the *users* array. Here's how you can modify your code to do that:

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
var users = [];

async function hashPass(pass) {
  try {
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);        
    console.log(`Hashing Password: ${pass}`);
    const hashedPass = await bcrypt.hash(pass, salt);
    console.log(`Hashed Password: ${hashedPass}`);

    return hashedPass;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

async function createUser() {
  const password = await hashPass('pass');

  users.push({
    'ID': 0,
    'Name': 'Ali',
    'Email': 'alihaisul.me@gmail.com',
    'Password': password
  });

  console.log(users);
}


createUser();
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation using the createUser function. I understood better this way.

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait for the `hashPassword` promise to finish. Note that `async` functions are promises at the end.

```
hashPass('pass').then(password => {
users.push({
    'ID': 0,
    'Name': 'Ali',
    'Email': 'alihaisul.me@gmail.com',
    'Password': password
})

console.log(users)

});
```